# Exclude records from table

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, exists

I have a parent and child table where a parent reference number has multiple entries in child table with status Pending, Success and Rejected. I need a query which will give me an output of only reference numbers which has status Success and Rejected. Even if there is one pending status for the reference number in child table the reference number should not be listed.

```
CREATE TABLE SI_DETAIL
  ( "S_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE);
    
    
CREATE TABLE SI_TRANSDETAIL
  ( "S_NO"  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "SL_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "EXE_DATE" DATE,
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE));
    
    
Insert into SI_DETAIL (S_NO,CREATED_DATE) values ('1000',to_date('29-11-22','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into SI_DETAIL (S_NO,CREATED_DATE) values ('1001',to_date('01-12-22','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into SI_DETAIL (S_NO,CREATED_DATE) values ('1002',to_date('30-11-22','DD-MM-RR'));

    
    
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1000','1',to_date('30-11-22','DD-MM-RR'),'REJECTED');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1000','2',to_date('01-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'SUCCESS');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1000','3',to_date('02-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'SUCCESS');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1001','1',to_date('02-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'SUCCESS');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1001','2',to_date('03-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'PENDING');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1001','3',to_date('04-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'PENDING');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1001','4',to_date('05-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'PENDING');
Insert into SI_TRANSDETAIL (S_NO,SL_NO,EXE_DATE,STATUS) values ('1002','1',to_date('04-12-22','DD-MM-RR'),'PENDING');
```

I have tried using below query now and achieving the desired output. The output should only return 1000 as it has no pending child records.
Is there a better solution

```
SELECT S_NO FROM SI_TRANSDETAIL DTL
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT S_NO FROM SI_DETAIL HD
               WHERE  DTL.S_NO = HD.S_NO  
                      AND CREATED_DATE < SYSDATE - 1
                      AND HD.S_NO NOT IN (SELECT S_NO 
                                          FROM   SI_TRANSDETAIL SUB 
                                          WHERE  STATUS = 'PENDING' 
                                                 AND SUB.S_NO = HD.S_NO));
```

Comment: Please share your sample data as text in the question, not as a linked image.

Comment: Do you mean C.status <>'Pending' , as from the query it looks like you have mentioned c.status<>'P' or you can use NOT LIKE 'P%'

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting the S_NO and nothing else, I would use `minus`. It works like `union` in that the two queries must have the same number of columns and matching column types.

```
select s_no
from si_detail
where created_date < sysdate - 1
minus
select s_no 
from si_transdetail
where status = 'PENDING'
```

If you are going to include dates or other data in your results, you will need to make the above a subquery and then join it back to another table.